# Analogue of conditional expectations when conditioning on inequalities.

Tags: probability-theory

I am really stuck on taking a simple concept and extending/finding its analogue.

For example this is the conditional expectations formula:
$$E(x|y)= \int_a^bx\frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}dx$$

**I want to use this definition format** and extend it to a slightly different problem.
$$E(x^2-1|a\leq x \leq b)= \int_?^?(x^2-1)\frac{f(x=x,a\leq x \leq b)}{f(a\leq x \leq b)}dx$$

How does this problem change if I condition on another random variable $y$.

$$E(x^2-1|a\leq y \leq b)= \int_?^?(x^2-1)\frac{f(x=x,a\leq y \leq b)}{f(a\leq y \leq b)}dx$$

How do I express the inequality of a $\leq x \leq b$ in the pdf using Bayes formula? Very simple if I am using a CDF but what I am dealing with pdf's because I am taking an expectations.

I am trying to find the exact analogue of equation 1 into equations 2 and 3.

**Comment Question**

Let's use the equation of the conditon expectation to recreate equation 1.

$$
E(x|y)=E[X\mid A] = \frac{E[X\mathbf{1}_A]}{P(A)}=\frac{\int_?^?x\ \mathbf{1(y=y)}dx}{f(y)}.
$$

How does the indicator function dissapear and appear in the bounds of the intergration and then create the joint pdf $f(x,y)$ as in equation 1. Thank you.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is something like $\mathbb{E}[g(x) \mid a\leq x\leq b] = \frac{\int_a^b g(x)f(x){\rm d}x}{\int_a^b f(x){\rm d}x}$ where $f(x)$ is the PDF.

Comment: Both question and the comment above are quite sloppy: $x$ (and $y$) have very different meaning in the left-hand and right-hand sides of the equality. One should use different symbols for random variables and integration variables e.g. 
$$
E[X\mid Y=y] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x\frac{f_{(X,Y)}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}dx.
$$

Comment: I understand but we get each others comments.

Answer (score 4):

When you define a conditional expectation, it does not matter whether the condition is equality or inequality. What does matter is whether or not the probability of condition is zero. When $P(A) >0$, the conditional expectation is defined as 
$$
E[X\mid A] = \frac{E[X\mathbf{1}_A]}{P(A)}.
$$ 
(In your particular case, see Kibble's comment.)

However, when the event has zero probability, the conditional expectation is not defined in general. Nevertheless, *by convention*, even in the case where $P(Y=x)= 0$ one writes 
$$
r(x) = E[X\mid Y=x] 
$$
to denote the *regression function* which satisfies $r(Y) = E[X\mid Y]$. If $(X,Y)$ have a joint density, then *a version of* $r$ is given by the formula you write (but there may be some other versions too).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I made an edit above with a comment question.

Comment: @jessica, I didn't get that. What did you edit? Your question was last edited 39 minutes ago.